# Twilio SMS Request url response is unexpected

Tags: google-apps-script, sms, twilio

I configured a twilio phone number with sms and set the messaging request url to a [twimlets.com/echo](http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%3CMessage%3EWhy%3C%2FMessage%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&) url
 that returns....

[image]

When I send an sms to the twilio number, a "Why" response comes back as expected.

When I change the request url to point to my [web-app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby0SMam0UNYjf6o85nX9WYzQYPPoBj_HQFr1-KLNuw/dev?cat=654321), which returns output that looks like this...

[image]

The inbound sms is logged, but no "Checking.." response comes back to the sms client.

Looking at the inbound log for the number, I see the message was received, but with a warning...

[image]

Further inspection finds the body of the response is html indicating a mis-direction somehow.

[image]

now, changing the url from https: to http: I see the following.

[image]

As you have figured out by now, this webapp is a google apps script web app hosted on google drive... any clue why this [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby0SMam0UNYjf6o85nX9WYzQYPPoBj_HQFr1-KLNuw/dev?cat=654321) would be failing when called by twilio, but not from my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help Philnash, using incognito mode led me to discover that the problem was that I had published my apps script web app incorrectly.

- create a new version of my apps script File > Manage versions
- publish the new version (and be sure to select the new version #)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just clicked on the [link you provided as your application](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby0SMam0UNYjf6o85nX9WYzQYPPoBj_HQFr1-KLNuw/dev?cat=654321) and was met with a page telling me I did not have permission to view the script. My guess is that's the page Twilio is getting right now and why you're able to see the XML but Twilio sees HTML. I'd take a look at the permissions for the script and try to open it up so that Twilio is able to see the page. Checking in a browser in private/incognito mode should help.